# Can I remove the login name?

Tags: gui-design, accounts

I am currently working on an enterprise software program. Our user(client) will have only one account individually, so that they don't need to change their account in most of the cases. And they are forced to log in before they can see any page. So is it OK if I remove the login name and just show a logout icon instead?

Here is my mockup
[image: header design]

Comment: You say in most cases they don't need to change their account. Under what circumstances might they need to do that?

Comment: By normal case, they don't.  But they might need to change into coworker's account if his coworker is ill or something.

Comment: Do you associate an icon with the account? Many sites just shown the avatar/icon as a clickable dropdown menu

Comment: That gear looking thing is what I would click if I needed to change something in my account.  Is that what that does?

Comment: @MobyD  Yes, you can setup personal preference here

Comment: @Ben Brocka  I thought about that before, but currently we only have two options here, preference and logout. It would be strange if I use drop-down in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If it can happen that they need to change accounts, it will surely happen theat they forget they did so (Ever had your boy-/girlfrient check webmail from your computer?). 
So: Unless something else on the page e.g. content will be noticably different, I would definitely include some kind of reminder to who is logged in (i.e. in whose name the user is acting, right?).

However, maybe this does not necessarily need to be the classic username in the corner.

What about showing a large "Welcome back !" in a splash screen manner for one second at the beginning of each session? (Just an idea from the top of my head)

Comment: I hate it when my boy/girlfriend checks her enterprise software programs on my computer.  So frustrating.

Comment: @Heiko Haller: The chance to change account is quite low, should below 0.1%. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Just an optimization.

If you would be willing to remove the username field, you could use a 'person' icon instead of the icon, making it clear for your user that he needs to be there to change everything concerning his account.